# How can i run a button automatically every second until de if condition be true?

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

I need that a button can run automatically every 1-2 seconds, and, when the if condition (that i have in the method which is used by the button) is fulfilled, this function must be stopped.

**I've tried this but it wasn't what i wanted because with this code the button only runs one time:**

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Consulta.performClick();

        }
    }, 1000);
```

**onClick of my button:**

```
 public void consultaBD(View view)
{

    DB db = new DB(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
    String buscar = text_view.getText().toString();
    String[] datos;
    datos=db.buscar_reg(buscar.trim());
    db.infraccion(buscar.trim());

    if(datos[2] =="Encontrado")
    {

        App.matricula=buscar;
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MatriculasActivity.class));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),datos[2],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),datos[2],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method would be to use Timers to initiate the button click every `x` seconds. However, in this answer I'll stick with the method you're using. Your handler appears to be incorrect, try something like this instead:

Replace your handler with:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Consulta.performClick();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

And initiate it with: (where 1000 is the time (in milliseconds) between each execution)

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

**UPDATE:**

You have also requested that the event is fired when the text inside of a textbox is changed. To do this, you need to create a new event listener (make sure you replace `field1` with the actual reference to your textbox):

```
field1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {

         /* Add the Handler Call here */
         handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);

     }
});
```

Comment: okay, now i have what you have written and works, the problem is that when the if condition is fulfilled and the new activity is opened, the runnable method still running and the activity start to do something like "close-open" all the time, how can i fix this problem?

Comment: maybe this explanation can help you to understand me, this part of the program has an editText where the user write, if the user has written an specific word that is in a database, automatically, the program open the new activity, the user can't press the button, the process must to be automatically, when the program detect that this word is in the editText, the new activity is opened...

Comment: So you want the above code to execute, when the user types into a textbox - instead of pressing a button?

Comment: Yes, for example, I have in a database the word "dog", if the user write "cat", nothing happen, but if the user write "dog", a new activity (how you can see in my code) is opened, and this must to be automatically

Comment: I still having the same error of my first comment because when the program see that the word in the textbox, is the correct word, the new activity is opened but the method runnable continue running so the app "fails", is there any way of stop the method runnable when the correct word has been found?

Comment: Yes - place an `if` statement inside the `consultaBD()` method and check if the database returned a valid value. If it did, then close the listener using `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages();`